# How to verify a Bearer token with .pfx certificate and password in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, token, pfx

The below code works if I try to verify a token with a secret but now I want to verify the token with .pfx certificate and the password. How can this be achieved?

```
jwt.verify(token, secret, options, function(err, decoded) {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To verify Token you need to convert your .pfx file to .pem file, it can be easily done using 'https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html' or you can even use a module called 'pemutils' & then the following code can be used to verify the Token.

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var fs = require('fs');
var options = { algorithms: ['RS256'] };
var cert = fs.readFileSync('src/cert.pem');  
var token = 'xxxx.xxxx.xxxx';

jwt.verify(token, cert , options , function(err, payload) {
    if(err)
    {
        console.log("Token verification failed: " + err) 
    }
    else{
        console.log("Token Verified: " + JSON.stringify(payload))
    }
});
```